# web.xml - JSP - tomcat related issue

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web.xml, jsp-tags

I have one JSP file running on Tomcat6 (Eclipse IDE). I added one `jsp-config` tag to my `web.xml` file. 
The `JSP` was not giving the correct result to me so I "Cleaned the tomcat directory" (using eclipse) and its fine now. But issue is every time when I am changing this tag (`jsp-config`) values I have to clean the tomcat directory. Is is supposed to be like this? or am I doing something wrong? My `web.xml` is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Thanks

Comment: what changes you do that you need to clean the directory

Comment: @ankur-singhal i am making the value of "el-ignored" as true->false false->true

Comment: does [this] (stackoverflow.com/questions/6808418/can-eclipse-automatically-refresh-tomcat-app) helps you